# Need help in fixing an ambiguous sentence

Tags: sentence, ambiguity

Need help in fixing the ambiguous sentence below:

> 11 products are supported by single engineer

What I want to mean is that in the 11 product, each product is only supported by one engineer; not all of the 11 products are supported by a single engineer. What is the best way to express this idea without being too wordy but at the same time leave no room for ambiguity?

> 11 products are supported by single engineer each

or

> 11 products, each of them supported only by a single engineer

Comment: 11 products, each supported by a separate, dedicated engineer; or: 11 engineers, one dedicated to each of the 11 products.

Comment: "**The** 11 products are supported by **a** single engineer each" works. "11 products, each (of them) supported (only) by a single engineer" is also a good alternative.

Answer (score 2):

> For every product, there is one supporting engineer

Or if a numeric qualifier is needed:

> For each of the 11 products, there is one supporting engineer.